# Link around button to button that links

Tags: javascript, html, grails

So I had this code:

```
<g:link class="create" action="create" params="${params}">
    <input type="button" value="New Field Trip Location">
</g:link>


<g:set var="paramsArray" value="$params" />
<button type="button" onClick="location.href='${createLink(controller:'fieldTripLocation', action:'create', params: $params)}'">New Field Trip Location</button>
```

The first code segment works on chrome and such but I have been told it is bad style having a link around a button. To fix this I tried to add code segment 2 using a paramsArray variable to pass my dynamic sized parameters but am unsure how to send my params variable(more like an array made up of a bunch of different variables such as index and cameFrom) to the next view. So overall summary: I have ugly bad code that works but want to fix it up but can't seem to pass multiple dynamic params and need your help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use just a link with proper css style:

```
<g:link class="create linkButton" action="create" params="${params}">
    New Field Trip Location
</g:link>

<style type="text/css">
.linkButton {
  font: bold 11px Arial;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  color: #333333;
  padding: 2px 6px 2px 6px;
  border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-right: 1px solid #333333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
  border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}
</style>
```

Comment: The problem with the css is the guy before me is using a stylesheet for buttons that I can't find or see. I did make a css for the buttons in chrome but those fell apart when on IE or Firefox so I was trying to standardize.

Comment: If project is online I could look at it and check if I could find it.

Comment: Would a picture work? I can't share too much of the code for legal reasons unfortunately haha

Comment: I'm talking about source code of views. With firebug (or any other frontend help) you can easily check css sources.

Comment: `<g:set var="paramsArray" value="$params" />` Was the way to do it however:
                    `<g:set var="paramsArray" value="[camefrom:'trip', tripId: params?.tripId]" />` or w/e your params are is probably better form but yes Im giving you the answer as that is how anyone else should do this.